# Nginx - listen on multiple domains, serve only some content on one domain

Tags: nginx

I have a web application that serves 2 different domains, let's call them `eu.example.com` and `us.example.com`.

I have set up nginx in front of the application, listening on both domains:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name eu.example.com us.example.com;

    ...
}
```

Now the US team decided they want to have a blog on `us.example.com/blog`, which should point to WordPress on another server.

I can achieve this by adding a new location directive to my nginx server configuration:

```
location /blog {
   proxy_pass https://us-wordpress.example.com/blog;
}
```

The problem is that the US blog is now also available from `eu.example.com/blog`. I tried wrapping it in an if:

```
location /blog {
   if ($hostname = us.example.com) {
       proxy_pass https://us-wordpress.example.com/blog;
   }
}
```

But then I get an error from nginx saying: `"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block`.

I could achieve the same by having separate `server { ... }` directives per domain, but that would be duplicating most of the configuration, and I'd prefer to avoid that.

Is there a way to achieve this in a sensible way?

Comment: Separate `server` blocks is the sensible way, but place all of your duplicated configuration into a separate file and `include` it into both.

Comment: @RichardSmith It seems your suggestion is the best thing to do. Peter already provided an answer with this, but if you want to add the same answer with your name on it, please do so, and I'll accept that as the right answer.

Comment: Please accept Peter's answer - I am feeling magnanimous today :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should achieve it like you said, with separate server blocks, and another [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include)d file for both servers to avoid duplication.

```
server{ 
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name us.example.com;
    include commonfile;
    location /blog {
        ...
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name eu.example.com;
    include commonfile;
}
```

Comment: oh Richard Smith already said this in a comment instead of answer...